# Warning : assignment to int from int* makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, integer, warnings

I'm tring to code a C code that sorts the args given from the smallest to the largest, but I keep getting this error :

warning: assignment to ‘int’ from ‘int *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
80 |             array[x] = av[i];

I tried to change "int array[x];" to "int *array[x];" but I get another error because of this line -> gnome_sort(array, size);

Can someone help me with this? Thx

```
void gnome_sort(int *array, int size)
{
    int tmp; 
    for (int i = 1; i < size;) {
        if (array[i-1] <= array[i])
            ++i;
        else {
            tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[i-1];
            array[i-1] = tmp;
            --i;
            if (i == 0)
                i = 1;
        }
    }
}
 
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int i;
    int x = 0;
    int array[ac];
    x = 0;
    for (i = 1; av[i] != NULL; i++) {
        array[x] = atoi(av[i]);
        x++;
    }
    size_t size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        gnome_sort(array, size);
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main(int ac, int **av)` is wrong among other things.

Comment: @Fixx This for loop  for (x = 0; av[i] != NULL; x++); is an infinite loop.:)

Comment: I fixed it to main(int ac, char **av) but it doesnt change much I keep getting the errors

Comment: Please use the conventional names for the `main()` arguments: `argc` and `argv`.

Comment: `array[x] = av[i];` this line is wrong. `array` is an array of integers while `av` is an array of pointers to `char`.

Comment: Why do you need a loop to count the arguments? The argument count is in `ac`.

Comment: If you're trying to get the numeric value of each argument, use `array[x] = atoi(av[i]);`

Comment: The 1st argument to `gnome_sort()` is supposed to be an array. `atoi(array)` returns a single integer, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

i have a suggestion not a solution, tray to pass the array to the function rather than using a void function and return it after modification.